# How to sort only filtered result set, not entire table

Tags: mysql, performance, sorting

I read here somewhere that `ORDER BY` sorts only the filtered set when there is a `WHERE` clause present. I'm seeing some different results though.

My table has ~550k records, the following query completes in ~2.5 seconds:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    scrapings
WHERE MATCH (title, descr) AGAINST ("young" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY
    dt DESC
LIMIT 100
```

By removing the `ORDER BY` clause the time gets cut to ~0.1 seconds. How can I make it sort only the filtered results?

Oh and I also tried removing the `WHERE` clause just to make sure it wasn't taking ~2.5 seconds actually sorting the filtered results.

Oh 2: Here it is `EXPLAIN`ed:
[image]

Oh 3: Here is the DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `scrapings` (
  `url` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `dt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `descr` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `image` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `domain` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`url`,`dt`),
  UNIQUE KEY `image` (`image`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`,`descr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Comment: put an index on dt

Comment: @DanielA.White this reminds me of https://i.chzbgr.com/full/6044249600/hEA007461/ I'm trying to have it sort only the filtered results, not speed up the entire table sort.

Comment: try it. whats the harm?

Comment: @DanielA.White not necessarily harm but it's not what I'm trying to do. It could speed up the query but it's defeating the purpose of the question.

Comment: How many rows match on that `MATCH`?

Answer (score 0):

mysql sorts only the selected rows.

If you wanted to know why the order by took so long especially when the column has no index(So Daniels suggestions makes sense), is because mysql creates a temporary table of the results and sorts them.

if someone is interested in the internal workings read some of *Understanding MySQL Internals: Discovering and Improving a Great Database*

But where did you hear or  read about mysql sorted only the filtered set when a where clause is involved.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that query will be executed is:

1. Filter using the `WHERE`
2. Sort the entire filtered set by the `ORDER BY` (no index is useful here).  Note that it had to reach into the records to find `dt` so it could sort.
3. Deliver the first 100 (LIMIT)

If you remove the `WHERE`, then it will either sort the entire table, or (if you have `INDEX(dt)` it might use the index to avoid the sort.

If you remove just the `ORDER BY` and lots of rows matched, then it will just deliver whatever 100 rows it found first.  This may be noticeably faster.